# Ramsauer–Townsend effect and Thermal Runaway in Thyratrons / (vacuum tubes)

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electrical-engineering, ionization-energy, ions

A few years ago an EE told me that the Townsend effect was involved in thermal runaway within vacuum tubes. I can't seem to find any specifics on this on the internet. Can anyone disprove / verify and / or explain the claim?

Thanks.

Comment: One could argue that the Townsend effect actually opposes avalanche since it minimizes ionizing collisions that would lead to more current.

Comment: @JonCuster , Indeed, that was my thought too. I wonder what he meant? I find the subject generally interesting because the townsend effect is such a simple proof of QM without the need for fancy equipment.